# Problem validating @PathVariable url on spring 3 mvc

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

HI am starting to use spring 3 mvc and have run into a problem that don't know how to solve;

I am trying to validate a url `@pathvariable` using:

```
public String showGsscFormWithVenueId (@Valid 
        @Pattern(regexp="(0?[1-9]*)",message="venueid.not.number")
        @PathVariable String venueId, BindingResult result, Model model) {
```

However I am getting an exception saying:

> Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!

I've read about it on the internet and it says that bindingresult has to be after your model but my model is the pathVariable.

The only reason that I am using binding result is because I want to show the `message="venueid.not.number"` on the jsp. Therefore, could you please let me know if there is any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `@PathVariable` parameter fails validation, then Spring will add the error to the request's `BindingResult` automatically, you don't need to do that yourself.

As the error suggests, you can only declare an explicit `BindingResult` parameter when you're using form-base model objects. It's not intended to be used with `@PathVariable`.

Comment: @tsunade21: Using standard JSTL `<fmt:message>` tags. The message key is auto-generated from the field name, I can't remember exactly what it uses.