# How to make customEditor in Spring dynamic enough to call validation on appropriate methods

Tags: spring, rest, validation

I have recently learned that @PathVariable cannot be validated in Spring unless we use Custom Editor.

I got the answer from the following link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002325/1787314

but seems like all my @PathVariables would need their own class (e.g. Name.class CustomerNumber.class and so) and that will a lot of classes just for the validation.

is there a way to write a Class dynamic enough to validate based on which method is being called so for e.g. if getName is called with @PathVariable name then
DynamicEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport would validate name and if @PathVariable is id then same Editor will be called but this time only id will be validated.

I hope I was able to phrase my question properly. I am new to Spring so I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: try the way in this [post](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/validating-spring-mvc-request-mapping-method-parameters/). It use JSR-303 Validation for the arguments in Spring MVC request.

Comment: @Mavlarn I tried that and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: http://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: @Mavlarn The solution that you posted works with RequestParam

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can use [regexp for URI](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) to validate. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}")
public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
    // ...
}
```

And I found this [post](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/validating-spring-mvc-request-mapping-method-parameters/), it use JSR-303 Validation with spring. But I didn't try it. I hope it can help.

[Update]

Based on the response above,the JSR-303 way seems don't work.
The solution in [this post](http://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/) can work.

Hope it can help.