# validators are not working in spring controller like @size and @Min

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, spring-annotations

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sites/{version}/variants", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<PageVariantData> getVersions(
            @Validated 
            @PathVariable(required = true)  @Size(min=3, max=10) int version))
```

Here version value is not validating against size.
It is always giving 200 response.

Comment: `@Valid` does not work on `@PathVariable` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values

Comment: Is your controller annotated with `@Validated`? Based on the [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11041) it will work if the controller (not the parameter) is `@Validated` and doesn't implement interfaces.