# Custom validation for @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, validation, interface, annotations

There is a controller accepting code as a path variable

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/currency")
@Validated
public class CurrencyController {

    @GetMapping("/gif/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> getChangeGif(@PathVariable @Code String code){
        // some implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to use my own annotation to validate code as I want

```
@Target( { FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy =  CodeValidator.class)
public @interface Code {

    public String message() default "error message";

    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And here is the validator

```
public class CodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Code, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Code constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String code, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // validator implementation
        return false;
    }
}
```

For some reason when requests come, validation just skipps, and controller continue working without it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values

Comment: This code is working fine. See if you are missing anything in project. Try first with standard validation like `@Length(min=2)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, since you asked specifically for `@PathVariable` validation and I just stumbled upon this myself:

If you are in a real life project, you might also have an authorization check that prevents the validation. The typical order the validation and pre-authorize checks in spring are done are the following and maybe not intuitive:

1. Validation of `@RequestBody` parameter
2. Performing `@PreAuthorize` check
3. Validation of `@PathVariable` parameter

So it happened to me that I thought the path variable validation was not working in contrast to the request body validation - but it was simply covered by the authorization check ;-)