# Hibernate Min annotation message is not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate

My Controller class looks like this, I am creating an API in which i am sending pageNo and pageSize as PathVariable and before path Variable I have added Valid annotation and in @Min I gave one message-

```java
@RestController
public class ProfileController {
  @GetMapping("/profiles/{pageSize}/{pageNo}")  
  public ResponseEntity<List<ProfileResponse>> getProfile( @Min(value = 1,message="Page Number must be Positive Number") @Valid @PathVariable Integer pageNo, @Valid @Min(value = 1, message="Page Size must be Positive Number") @PathVariable Integer pageSize)  
  {
    //code
  }
}
```

In the postman when I send pageNumber as 0 then it throws an error "Page index must not be less than one" and it is not giving me message what I have define. any work around?

Comment: Please rewrite your question with readable format. [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @NishitCharania Now I have edited my questions, can you please help me in this?

Comment: This is even worse, code is code not a quote. It is only a snippet (whereas what you have more on your controller is also important). So there is too little information and what is there is poorly formatted.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Reformatted the question again

Comment: Your ctronller needs `@Validated` to have those annotations be effective. What you see currently is the exception from constructing a `PageRequest`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Validated annotation also not working , still getting default message "PageIndex must not be less than.one"

Comment: You also need to enable the processing of that annotation by registering a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Valid only support for the bean validation:

> The Spring Framework supports JSR-303 Bean Validation adapting it to Spring's Validator interface.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Also, community asking to add this feature in spring and that is open
Ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11041

Some workaround you can find to understand more at: [How to validate Spring MVC @PathVariable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values)

Comment: No it isn't, you can enable it if you add `@Validated` to the bean and register the post processor. Drawback is that you will get a 500 instead of a 400, which could be circumvented by a dedicated `@ExceptionHandler` for this case.

Comment: can you please elaborate, that helps me to understand your view and gain knowledge. @M.Deinum

Comment: Hope you have checked the links that I have added... and try to determine that we can do using some workaround. I am Happy to learner :)

Comment: The links do provide the "workaround" with the processor and the said annotation. However as both serve a different purpose they also result in different error handling strategies.