# Spring Boot : Cannot validate empty PathVariable using @NotBlank, etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, annotations

I cannot validate a string type path variable in Spring Boot app. I tried the suggestions mentioned on [How to validate Spring MVC @PathVariable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values), but not working. So, do I have to create a custom validator just for validating a `@PathVariable` value?

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DataController {


    @GetMapping("/employees/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<Employee>>> findAllByCode(
            // @PathVariable("code") @Valid @NotBlank String code) {
            @PathVariable("code") @NotBlank String code) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Any idea about the solution?

Comment: Does anybody else has never used validation ever before?

Comment: The option from the linked page works fine for me, it looks like you just need to override org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleBindException in a class, which will extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandle and having annotated as @ControllerAdvice. This is just one of the ways.