# Validating @PathVariable if it is null in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, lombok

In Spring Boot applications, I have problem with validating `@PathVariable` for `long` type  and even if I tried the following approaches, I cannot validate `@PathVariable` for null values (whereas I can using `@RequestParam`):

- Trying to use `@Valid` and `@NotNull` annotations before `@PathVariable` in the controller
- Using primitive type (`long` instead of `Long`)
- Adding `@Validated` annotation to Controller as class level besides using `@Valid` and `@NotNull` annotations in the Controller method.

So, here is my Controller method and I am wondering, if it is not possible to validate null path variable? Actually Swagger does not let the user send request with null path variable, but Postman lets.

```
@GetMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<CategoryDto>> findById(@PathVariable long id) {
    // ...
}
```

Here is the error message after sending null path variable on Postman:

> "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ":id""
> }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate Spring MVC @PathVariable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419234/how-to-validate-spring-mvc-pathvariable-values)

Comment: how did you send "null path variable" on postman? (I hope `/categories/` (then just define a 40x (x as you like) response on `@GetMapping("/categories")`)... if it was `/categegories/null/`...what would you excpect?)

Comment: path variables should *never* be nullable. On the other hand I can recommend: to use "nullable datatypes" on "nonnullable fields" ...

Comment: @Alien Actually I read that page, but I am not sure if you look at the dates of the answers. I think during these 6-7 years, something must be solved. That's why I needed to create a new question.

Comment: @xerox Just make id fields empty and then try to send null id.